# jQuery self made tabs plugin problems

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried to make a small tab plugin and used code from some learning site I don't remember.
Problem: when I initialize plugin 2 times on a page it works at both places same time.
Here's a pen with a complete case: https://codepen.io/leshiq/pen/XWJjmxy

Here's plugin's code:

```
(function($){       
  jQuery.fn.lightTabs = function(options){

    var createTabs = function(){
      tabs = this;
      i = 0;
      if ($(tabs).children().first().children().length < 2) {
        tabs_list = $(tabs).children().first().children().children();
      } else {
        tabs_list = $(tabs).children().first().children();
      }
      console.log(tabs_list);
      showPage = function(i){
        $(tabs).children().last().children().hide();
        $(tabs).children().last().children().eq(i).show();
        tabs_list.removeClass("active");
        tabs_list.eq(i).addClass("active");
      }

      showPage(0);
      console.log($(tabs).children().last().children());

      tabs_list.each(function(index, element){
        $(element).attr("data-page", i);
        i++;                        
      });

      tabs_list.click(function(){
        showPage(parseInt($(this).attr("data-page")));
      });       
    };    
    return this.each(createTabs);
  };  
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by the problem of "it works at both places same time." Sounds like that's what you _would_ want. Typo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you're using variables without *declaring* them. That is defining the variables globally, causing the two tab widgets to share state. Fix:

```
(function($){       
  jQuery.fn.lightTabs = function(options){

    function createTabs() {
      const tabs = this;
      const tabs_list = ($(tabs).children().first().children().length < 2)
        ? $(tabs).children().first().children().children()
        : $(tabs).children().first().children();
      console.log(tabs_list);
      function showPage(i) {
        $(tabs).children().last().children().hide();
        $(tabs).children().last().children().eq(i).show();
        tabs_list.removeClass("active");
        tabs_list.eq(i).addClass("active");
      }

      showPage(0);
      console.log($(tabs).children().last().children());

      tabs_list.each(function(index, element){
        $(element).attr("data-page", index);
      });

      tabs_list.click(function(){
        showPage(parseInt($(this).attr("data-page")));
      });       
    }

    return this.each(createTabs);
  };  
})(jQuery);
```

Working codepen: https://codepen.io/apoco/pen/gObwPwR

Comment: Thanks for solvation! I really need to study more)